# Influxdb buckets or tags for storing users?

Tags: tags, influxdb, bucket

First time working with influxdb and im trying to optimize a project that might have a lot of users. My question is, should time series data for each user be stored with different tags or in different buckets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends.

If number of users are **not infinite** or too many (i.e. compare to other tags relatively speaking) and these users will be filtered **a lot** when you are doing "group by", you should put these users as tags.

Otherwise, treat them in fields.

Tag values are indexed and field values aren’t in InfluxDB. Tags consume a lot of memory and you want to make best of resources on the most important stuff. The more tags, the more diversity of each tag, [the higher the cardinality](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/write-data/best-practices/resolve-high-cardinality/), the higher memory usage, the more probability you will hit the OOM issue.

See more best practices [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/write-data/best-practices/schema-design/#use-tags-and-fields).